# what is the best security practice to escape my data before submitting it into my database in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have written a function for insertion into my database. i have a small doubt .

**Is my below code provides good security  to escape my data before submitting it into my database?**

Please suggest me some solution for this if the below code does not provide good way of insetion of data into db
views.php

```
 <? echo form_open('Setups/subject'); ?> 
                 <? echo '<div id="level">'. $subjectname.' : '.form_input($fsubjectname); ?>  
                 <?  echo form_submit($submitbtn); 
                  echo form_reset($resetbtn);  
                  echo '</fieldset>'; ?>

   <? echo form_close(); ?>
```

controller.php

```
class Setups extends CI_Controller  {

function subject(){
    $this->load->helper('form'); 
    $this->load->model('Setupsmodel');

    if($this->input->post('subsubmit')){
        $this->Setupsmodel->entry_insert();
    }

    $data=$this->Setupsmodel->subjectsetup(); 
    $this->load->view('admin/setups/subject_setups',$data); 
  }
}
```

model.php

```
  class Setupsmodel extends CI_Model {

  function __construct()
{
    // Call the Model constructor
    parent::__construct();
}

function subjectsetup()
{
 $data['subjectname']='Enter Subject Name';  
 $data['fsubjectname']=      
  array('name'=>'subject_name','class'=>'input','size'=>30,'id'=>'txtsubject'); 

 $data['formtopic']='Subject Details Form';


 $data['submitbtn'] = array(
'name' => 'subsubmit',
'class' => 'button',
'value' => 'Submit',
'type' => 'submit',
'content' => 'Submit'

 );
  $data['resetbtn'] = array(
'name' => 'button',
 'class' => 'rsetbutton',
'value' => 'Reset',
'type' => 'reset',
'content' => 'Reset'
);

 return $data;   
}

//--------------Insertion of new record in the table subjectdetails into the db------------

function entry_insert(){
   $this->load->database();
   $data=array(
       'subject_name'=>$this->input->post('subject_name'));
$this->db->insert('subjectdetails',$data);
}   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not filtering your user input, so it's risky. Anyways, `CodeIgniter` comes with a Cross Site Scripting Hack prevention filter which can either run automatically to filter all POST and COOKIE data that is encountered, or you can run it on a per item basis. By default it does not run globally since it requires a bit of processing overhead, and since you may not need it in all cases. To filter data through the XSS filter you can use following method from [security class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/security.html)

```
$data = $this->security->xss_clean($data);
```

If you want the filter to run automatically every time it encounters POST or COOKIE data you can enable it by opening your application/config/config.php file and setting this

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

If you use the form validation class, it gives you the option of `XSS` filtering as well, using `set_rules` method of [form validation class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrulesasarray).

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('input_name', 'input label', 'xss_clean');
```

So in this case, you can use in your controller

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('subject_name', 'Subject Name', 'xss_clean|required');
if($this->form_validation->run())
{
    $this->Setupsmodel->entry_insert();
}
```

There `xss_clean` rule will filter the input and `required` rule will check whether the input is empty or not, so if validation is successful then your insert method will work.