# Codeigniter: how to sanitize a string?

Tags: codeigniter-3, sanitize

I have imported a string from excel sheet. Before inserting it to database, i want to sanitize it. Is there a builtin codeigniter function to sanitize such data? 
I believe $this->input->get() and $this->input->post() is only for GET and POST data.

Comment: My friend, This is a very large topic. Stack Overflow literally overflows with information on sanitizing and escaping data. Try using the search bar above. You can get questions tagged for CodeIgniter by staring your search with `[codeigniter]` followed by other terms, e.g. `[codeigniter]sanitize` or `[codeigniter]escape data` will provide a wealth of information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301521/what-is-the-best-security-practice-to-escape-my-data-before-submitting-it-into-m